# WSDL and SOAP Clarification

Tags: soap, wsdl

Can someone confirm or clarify:

**WSDL** describes a web service's API to the outside world

**SOAP** represents an actual transmission of a web service request/response

So, if I understand correctly, WSDL-compliant XML is wrapped inside of SOAP and passed over HTTP to the web service interface, unwrapped, validated against the WSDL, processed, and responded to.

Yes? No? Close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.

The WSDL describes the contract that a Web Service adheres to or, in other words, the format that the service expects to receive and transmit data in.

SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol) is one protocol by which Web Services communicate. SOAP will wrap the message with additional information. The message with the SOAP body carries must comply with the service's WSDL for the service to properly process the message.